# How can I add 2 aliased values in a Laravel query select together?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a tasks table which tracks the car odometer values of a task. A task relates to itself and has one previous task defined by a has one relationship. I'm trying to create a scope to pull in a complete_at_odometer value in the query.

This value is equal to a completed_at_odometer value on the previous task plus the frequency of which the current task needs to be repeated. For example the current Task A needs to be completed every 10 miles. The last task, Task B was completed at 5 miles. I'm trying to create a scope to add the value complete_at_odometer to the results which should equal 15.

Here's what I have so far:

```
public function scopeWithCompleteByOdometer($query)
{
    return $query
        ->join('tasks as oldTask', 'oldTask.current_task_id', '=', 'tasks.id')
        ->select(
            '*',
            'oldTask.completed_at_odometer as last_odometer',
            'tasks.distance_interval as interval'
        );
}
```

I'm not sure how can I add the values last_odometer and interval together whilst staying in the Database Layer of my application?

I'm using Laravel 7 and MySql 5.7.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `DB::raw` query:

```
return $query
    ->join('tasks as oldTask', 'oldTask.current_task_id', '=', 'tasks.id')
    ->select(DB::raw('(oldTask.completed_at_odometer + tasks.distance_interval) AS total'));
```

OR take sum from the result obtained like this

```
$a = $row->completed_at_odometer;
$b = $row->distance_interval;
$total = $a+$b
```